# "puya" vs "pulla"

Tags: etimología

Una **puya** es una punta de metal con la que se pincha a los animales, bien para que reaccionen a las órdenes o bien para castigarlos.

Una **pulla** es algo que se dice para pinchar a alguien, bien para que reaccione ante alguna situación o bien para humillarle.

A pesar de la (en mi opinión) OBVIA relación que existe entre ambas palabras, **el DLE dice que [puya](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UkBJr00) viene del latín *pugia*, mientras que [pulla](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Ucq3ASg) viene del portugués *pulha***... la cual a su vez y según [todos](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pulha) [los](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=pulha) [diccionarios](http://www.aulete.com.br/pulha) [portugueses](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/pulha) [consultados](http://dicionario-aberto.net/search/pulha) viene del español "pulla". ‍♂️

Mi pregunta: ¿en qué se puede haber basado la RAE (textos, registros, estudios) para afirmar que "pulla" **no** viene de "puya"... o viceversa? Más aún, ¿en qué para afirmar que "pulla" viene del portugués *pulha* en vez, por ejemplo, del italiano *puglia* como afirma la etimología portuguesa?

Comment: Y más aún: Corominas dice que la voz _pulla_ española es anterior a sus equivalentes portugués y francés, los cuales pueden ser castellanismos (la voz española sería del siglo XV). Más allá de eso dice que su origen es incierto pero puede venir de un cruce de _puya_ con _repullar_ "replicar satíricamente", que a su vez provendría del latín _repelere_, "rechazar".

Comment: Covarrubias (1611) dice que "llamose pulla de la Apulla tierra de Napoles, donde se empeçó a usar, y de alli se ha estendido a todo el mundo". :-)

Comment: Ambas son lenguas que provienen del latín, puede ser que antes de que se dividieran, se usara más en un sitio que en otro y luego el otro lo aceptara

Comment: En https://mobile.twitter.com/EtimosDirectos/status/1269542250536632321 hablaron de ello y coinciden con el autor en que en portugués hablan de origen español.